# ios:Instatinate View Controller is not working(View Controller is not pushing)?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In my project am parsing json from webservice and displaying in screen, am using stroyboards for my project, In my login pagem after entering user details am parsing json, is i receives status as 1 it will goto next page else it will show error message. Now my problem is it checks status but no loads next page. am using navigation controller. Here is the code what i hat i have tried to load view controller  but its not working

```
  -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
      NSLog(@"%@",redirectString);
    tweet = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    tweet = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@",tweet);
    if ([tweet isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){ //Added instrospection as suggested in comment.
        NSArray *yourStaffDictionaryArray = tweet[@"userDetail"];
        if ([yourStaffDictionaryArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){//Added instrospection as suggested in comment.
            for (NSDictionary *dictionary in yourStaffDictionaryArray) {
               if([[dictionary objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"status"]);
            NSLog(@"%@",redirectString);
            if([redirectString isEqualToString:@"CA"]) {
                NSLog(@"Prints 1");
                UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
                // Get instance of initial Viewcontroller from storyboard
                UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
                // Get instance of desired viewcontroller
                RTCommunityViewController *viewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"community_id"];
                //viewController.kApiKey = apikey;
                //viewController.kSessionId = sessionid;
                //viewController.kToken = token;
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                }
            else if([redirectString isEqualToString:@"CC"]) {
              NSLog(@"Prints 1");
              UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
              // Get instance of initial Viewcontroller from storyboard
              UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
              // Get instance of desired viewcontroller
              RTCounsellingViewController *viewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"community_id"];
              //viewController.kApiKey = apikey;
              //viewController.kSessionId = sessionid;
              //viewController.kToken = token;
              [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
          }
          else if([redirectString isEqualToString:@"mgar"]) {
              NSLog(@"Prints 1");
              UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
              // Get instance of initial Viewcontroller from storyboard
              UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
              // Get instance of desired viewcontroller
              MyGivingViewController *viewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"community_id"];
              //viewController.kApiKey = apikey;
              //viewController.kSessionId = sessionid;
              //viewController.kToken = token;
              [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
          }
            else if([redirectString isEqualToString:@""]){
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            NSLog(@"Prints 2");
            // Get instance of initial Viewcontroller from storyboard
            UINavigationController *navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MYhome1"];
            // Get instance of desired viewcontroller
            RTHomeViewController *viewController = (RTHomeViewController *)[navController topViewController];
            //viewController.kApiKey = apikey;
            //viewController.kSessionId = sessionid;
            //viewController.kToken = token;
            [self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
            }

            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [SingleTon sinlgeTon].myname = username;
            [defaults setObject:username forKey:@"firstname"];
            [defaults setObject:pass1 forKey:@"lastname"];
            [defaults setObject:valuestat forKey:@"USER_ID"];
            [defaults setObject:usertype forKey:@"USER_TYPE"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            NSLog(@"Data saved");
        }
        else if([[dictionary objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            UIAlertView *newAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"User Not Enabled!!" message:@"Contact Admin" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [newAlert show];
            [user resignFirstResponder];
            [pass resignFirstResponder];
            user.text = nil;
            pass.text = nil;
        }
        else if([[dictionary objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"invalid"]){
            UIAlertView *newAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Invalid User!!" message:@"Contact Admin" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [newAlert show];

        }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

I struck over here

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
                    // Get instance of initial Viewcontroller from storyboard
                    UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
                    // Get instance of desired viewcontroller
                    RTCommunityViewController *viewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"community_id"];
                    //viewController.kApiKey = apikey;
                    //viewController.kSessionId = sessionid;
                    //viewController.kToken = token;
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                    }
```

i cannot able to load viewController by instatinating. `View Controller is not pushing` Please help me how to do it. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have u logged `[dictionary objectForKey:@"status"]` ?

Comment: ya i logged in. but still its not working

Comment: What is the value you are getting for `[dictionary objectForKey:@"status"]` ?

Comment: wait let me add my full -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection code

Comment: Does this logs? `NSLog(@"%@",redirectString);`?

Comment: redirectstring is the parameter i pass from controller to login controller. Check my full code i have edited

Comment: What is the last value u logged?

Comment: did you mean redirectString

Comment: yes.. n what are u getting when u get JSON data?? where did u stuck?

Comment: see i editied my question by adding the answer for what u have asked

Comment: i Struck @ here UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
                // Get instance of initial Viewcontroller from storyboard
                UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
                // Get instance of desired viewcontroller
                RTCommunityViewController *viewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"community_id"];
               
              
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];

Comment: see i edited my question on where i got struck

Comment: It would help to see the output from all the NSLogs you've got, when you run the code. Also might be worth checking that the storyboard and the viewcontroller aren't nil?

Comment: So `viewController` is not pushing?

Comment: @Himanshu Joshi  ya thats the problem. how can i solve this please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];           

UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

RTCommunityViewController *viewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"community_id"];

//Comment this
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"community_id" sender:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should check one more time your storyboard? Didn't you forget to set Custom classes and StoryboardID in identity inspector for all scenes?

In similar situation in view controller this code worked for me:

```
RTCommunityViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"community_id"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```